# What is correct way to make custom slider module? slide update problems

Tags: views, blocks

I have a custom slider module but the problem is if I make a new slide, it won't appear before drupal cache is cleared. So how can I renew my slides in the module so cache clear isn't needed.

My Code:
.module file

```
function my_module_theme() {
   return array('slider' =>                  
           array(
            'variables' => array(
                '#attached' => array(
                    'library' => array(
                        'my_module/assets',
                    ),
                ),
              'slides' => my_module_get_slides(),
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Plugin\Block\FlexSlider.php file

```
class FlexSlider extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
     return array(
            '#theme' => 'slider'
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is wrong, as the *variables* key should not give default values that dynamically change. `hook_theme()` is not invoked every time a theme hook is necessary, but only then the theme hook registry needs to be re-built. The code invoking `hook_theme()` is the following one, in [`Registry::build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21Registry.php/function/Registry%3A%3Abuild/8.9.x).

```
  if ($cached = $this->cache->get('theme_registry:build:modules')) {
    $cache = $cached->data;
  }
  else {
    foreach ($this->moduleHandler->getImplementations('theme') as $module) {
      $this->processExtension($cache, $module, 'module', $module, $this->getPath($module));
    }

    // Only cache this registry if all modules are loaded.
    if ($this->moduleHandler->isLoaded()) {
      $this->cache->set("theme_registry:build:modules", $cache, Cache::PERMANENT, [
        'theme_registry',
      ]);
    }
  }
```

That explains why clearing the cache the code works.

Code that would work is similar to the following one.

```
function my_module_theme() {
  return array('slider' => array(
    'variables' => array(
      'slides' => NULL,
    ),
  ));
}

class FlexSlider extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'slider',
      '#slides' => my_module_get_slides(),
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array(
          'my_module/assets',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Depending on what returned from `my_module_get_slides`, `build()` could also need to set cache keys, cache contexts, or cache tags to make the output be cached, and invalidate the cache when necessary. See [Render API overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.9.x) for more details on how those values are used for rendered elements.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to drupal and this helped me a lot